# Does Log4j2 AsyncLogger follow insertion order?

Tags: log4j2

Suppose I have a single thread to keep writing logs using Log4j2 AsyncLogger, will the logs in the files follow the order of the calls? How many threads it uses to consume the log events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [message order bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2031) was fixed in version 2.10.0. So from this version the messages should be displayed in the order.
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837997/how-many-threads-does-log4j2-spawn-when-using-async-loggers) there is only one thread that writes to file